# What was Lazarus longing for, in Lk 16:21 ? :

Tags: luke, parables

We read in Lk 16:19-21:

> There was a rich man who was dressed in purple and fine linen and lived in luxury every day. At his gate was laid a beggar named Lazarus, covered with sores and longing to eat what fell from the rich man’s table.

<  Some say that rich Jews used to clean their fingers between two courses of the meal, with an inferior quality of bread which would be thrown out immediately after the cleaning.  Was Lazarus waiting for that kind of bread ? What do scholars say on the prospects ?

Comment: The are many interpretations of the parable, but I know of none that dwells on this particular detail.

Comment: "Some say that rich Jews used to clean their fingers between two courses of the meal, with an inferior quality of bread which would be thrown out immediately after the cleaning." Who says that?? That sounds preposterous.

Comment: Some commentators think the dogs brought some of the scraps to Lazarus, indicating that the dogs were well fee with the scraps,

Answer (score 2):

The key to answering this question is actually found in Matt 15:27 and Mark 7:28 where the Syrophoenician woman says:

> Matt 15:27 - And she said, "Yes Lord, but even the dogs eat the crumbs
> falling from their masters' table."

Thus, the image of the beggar, Lazarus, in Jesus parable is one where:

- despised dogs (an unclean animal) show more compassion to Lazarus than the rich man
- Lazarus must compete with such dogs for "crumbs" that fall from the rich man's table
- thus, Lazarus is treated like a dog (compare the traditional insult in 2 Sam 3:8 and 1 Sam 17:43 comparing a person to a dog!)

**APPENDIX - Textual Matter**

The text of Luke 16:21 is disputed.  The OP has quoted a valid translation of the NA28/UBS5 text (the most common text).  However, other MSS add two words: τῶν ψιχίων (the crumbs) which makes the verse read as as per the TR and Byzantine text:

> desiring to be fed with **the crumbs** which fell from the rich man’s
> table. Moreover the dogs came and licked his sores.

While not a fan of this late text (which is supported by only MSS from about the 6th century onwards), it makes explicit the conclusion reached above.

In his Textual Commentary on the GNT, Metzger suggests that τῶν ψιχίων ("the crumbs") was introduced and copied from Matt 15:27.

Comment: + upvoted for its educational value but I don't think it actually answers the OP's about the rich man cleaning his fingers.  Apropos of your comment regarding the text of Luke, it may be no accident that the poor man is named Lazarus, the name of the man Jesus' resurrected. There is an idea that parable was meant to criticize the Sadducees, who denied the resurrection. Some speculate that the rich man was meant to symbolize the high priest... and the [Sadducean dynasty](https://taylormarshall.com/2008/08/rich-man-and-lazarus-rich-man-is.html) of that time.

Comment: Dan Fefferman, the name Lazarus came from Eleazar, meaning 'God has Helped' in Hebrew. While Jesus friend Lazarus was a real person, the poor Lazarus was a character in Jesus' story. Is it not intriguing that Jesus chose the name meaning 'God has Helped' for the wretched poor man ?

Comment: @DanFefferman - The purpose of the parable may well have been as you suggest.  Concerning the rich man cleaning his fingers etc, I think that the ancients, based on their insertion of "the crumbs" may well have thought otherwise; hence my answer.